# Command line scripting with javascript (nashorn) on windows

Tags: javascript, windows, shell, nashorn

I would like to use javascript (specifically nashorn) for command line scripting under windows. By command line scripting I mean using javascript instead of a .bat file, for executing various command line utilities and processing their output. An official example is [here at oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/nashorn/shell.html).

There they show how you can execute shell commands from within a `.js` file with `$EXEC("ls -l")` and the output can be accessed in `$OUT` and `$ERR`, if you run it with
`jjs script.js -scripting -- params`. I did a lot of googling, and it is not mentioned anywhere (oracle and 3rd party blog posts, SO, etc) that this isn't supported on windows, but somehow, *all* of the examples are with `bash` commands. **Is this even possible on windows?**
So can I write in a `.js` script eg. `$EXEC("dir")` and process the output from `$OUT`?

How far I got:

- If I don't use the `-scripting` param for `jjs`, when the script hits the `$EXEC` command, I simply get `ReferenceError: "$EXEC" is not defined` so this is probably not the way to go.
- If I do use `-scripting` param, `$EXEC("cd c:")` throws the exception below. This suggests that I might be calling the commands in a wrong way, or that a path or something is not properly set up.

What am I missing here? Any idea is appreciated.

Environment details:

- Win 8.1
- Java 8, path to `jjs` (bin) set up properly in the system's environment variables.

The exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cd": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:382)
        at jdk.nashorn.tools.Shell.apply(Shell.java:383)
        at jdk.nashorn.tools.Shell.runScripts(Shell.java:312)
        at jdk.nashorn.tools.Shell.run(Shell.java:168)
        at jdk.nashorn.tools.Shell.main(Shell.java:132)
        at jdk.nashorn.tools.Shell.main(Shell.java:111)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cd": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptingFunctions.exec(ScriptingFunctions.java:166)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$test01.runScript(test01.js:8)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:535)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.invoke(ScriptFunction.java:209)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:378)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
        ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows `cd` and `dir` are shell commands, not a system executables (even on Linux `$EXEC("cd ./")` fails with the same "cannot find the file" error), but you can run bat scripts with your commands:

when `test.bat` contains

```
cd C:\Users
pwd
```

`jjs` evaluating

```
$EXEC("./test.bat")
```

will print

```
Volume in drive C has no label.
Volume Serial Number is ...

Directory of C:\Users

...
```

or call some non-interactive executables, like [label](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Label_%28command%29)

```
$EXEC("label C:System")
```

(it's just a first non-interactive thing that I found in `system32` folder; probably, it will fail because of insufficient rights, assuming, you're running `jjs` not as administrator.)

By the way, [internally Nashorn uses](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/nashorn/file/3780124b6dbb/src/jdk/nashorn/internal/runtime/ScriptingFunctions.java#l135) good old [java.lang.ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) for `$EXEC`, so all limitations of it apply here too.

Comment: Thank you for  the detailed answer. This is very unfortunate, because I would have to prepare a `.bat` wrapper for every shell command I would like to use in my scripts.

Comment: Well, if you'd like to maintain some state between them (like, current directory), it will not work if those are going to be separate scripts, because every `$EXEC` has it's separate 'context'. Also, for single or just small set of commands you can call `cmd` like this: `$EXEC('cmd /C "dir && cd C:\ && dir"')`

Comment: Thank you, I am aware that the context is lost between `$EXEC`s, but the absolute paths can be stored in the javascript and passed to the command line every time. And I can't think of any other state which I would make use of.

Comment: But your idea about using the `$EXEC` with `cmd` sounds good, I will try it.